# what Trafic between users and server must i encrypt in my app before deploying to play store?

Tags: encryption, google-play, google-play-console, policy, traffic

I have a simple app connected to a server via some sockets and the traffic is not yet encrypted users must log in or create accounts before using the app and afterwards traffic is shared between users and server. i want to know if i must encrypt all traffic or just the authentication and account creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https for all traffic (or an equivalent TLS-based protocol for non-HTTP traffic). Yes, encrypt and certificate-authenticate everything. For modern systems, there are vanishingly few cases where TLS is not the correct answer for network traffic. It is ubiquitously available across platforms, languages, and protocols.

On any modern network system you need an argument for why you *wouldn't* encrypt and authenticate the connection. It's not a matter of "must" you. It's a matter of "why wouldn't you?"